# Show that If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are rectifiable, then so is $S_1- S_2$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

**Recall:**

Definition. Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbf{R}^{n} .$ If the constant function is integrable over $S$, we say that $S$ is rectifiable, and we define the $(n$ dimensional) volume of $S$ by the equation
$$
v(S)=\int_{S} 1
$$

Theorem. A subset $S$ of $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ is rectifiable if and only if $S$ is bounded and Bd $S$ has measure zero.

> - **Question:** Show that If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are rectifiable, then so is$S_1- S_2,$ and
>
> $$v(S_1-S_2)=v(S_1)-v(S_1\cap S_2).$$
>
> Note: $v(S)$ means volume of $S.$

I need to show:

i) If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are bounded, then so is $S_1-S_2.$

ii) If $Bd S_1$ and $Bd S_2$ have measure zero, then so is $Bd(S_1-S_2).$

**I couldn't show ii), can you add answer? Thanks...**

Comment: $S_1-S_2\subset S_1$ so if $S_1$ has measure zero...

Comment: @DavideMaran I think, no because there was a typo in my opinion. I edted question. Could you see again, please? Thanks...

Comment: what does Bd mean? boundary?

Comment: @DavideMaran yes, boundary :)